# Is Cape Town, South Africa open and less busy around Christmas and New Year?

Tags: south-africa, public-holidays, cape-town

My girlfriend and I are planning a 6 month trip to the southern part of Africa. We are currently thinking about spending the time from Christmas and New Year in and around Cape Town in South Africa. Is this a good time to be in the city, specifically:

- Are touristic sites like Robben Island accessible at this time?
- Are hotels and hostels very crowded at this time?
- Is public transport working?
- Is there some life and public events going on in the city (which I assume for a town of that size)?

We think it could be quite special and more quiet than normal, because a lot of people living in Cape Town will be camping on garden route or national parks or going anything else. Are we thinking right?

Answer (score 3):

As with all popular tourist destinations, the Christmas to New Years Day period will be extremely busy in Cape Town. Be sure to book ahead for any activities that you would like to experience as well as for accommodation.

Unfortunately, while it may be true that many Capetonians are holidaying somewhere else, the rest of the country as well as around 100 000 visitors from other countries will be visiting Cape Town at this time.

Here is a [brief report](http://www.capetown.travel/uploads/files/Cape_Town_Industry_Dashboard_December_2014.pdf) on the numbers from 2014.

Tourist venues such as Robben Island will be accessible.

Hotels and hostels will be quite full.

Public transport such as buses, trains, and minibus taxis will be working.

There will be many events happening around the city.